# DataNucleus TypeConverter plugin is not registering correctly "java type not present in CLASSPATH"

Tags: maven, datanucleus

I am creating a DataNucleus TypeConverter plugin as a JAR, and then using this plugin in my main project.  However, I am getting the error `java type not present in CLASSPATH` even though from what I can tell, the classpath is correct.

Details below.

For my plugin, I have the following `plugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin id="com.advantagegroup.blue.jdo.datanucleus" name="blue.jdo.datanucleus" provider-name="advantagegroup">
    <extension point="org.datanucleus.type_converter">
        <type-converter name="org.json.simple.JSONObject -- java.lang.String"
                member-type="org.json.simple.JSONObject"
                datastore-type="java.lang.String"
                converter-class="com.advantagegroup.blue.jdo.datanucleus.JSONObjectConverter"
        />
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

I build my plug-in and add it to my main project.

In the main project, I run the enhancer using maven's `datanucleus-maven-plugin`.  The relevant parts of the POM file are below:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- START JSON simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END JSON simple -->

    <!-- START JDO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jdo</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-m6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-jdo-query</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END JDO -->

    // ...

    <!-- START internal dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.advantagegroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>blue-jdo-datanucleus</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END internal dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        // ...

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/jdoEnhancerLog4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I get the following DEBUG message from the enhancer:

```
2017-03-13 23:07:41 DEBUG Persistence:63 - TypeConverter for org.json.simple.JSONObject<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
```

Things go badly from there.

I can see that my plugin (`blue-jdo-datanucleus-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) and JSON Simple (`json-simple-1.1.1.jar`) **are both in the CLASSPATH**.   See log snippet below (edited for clarity):

```
[DEBUG] cmd.exe /X /C "C:\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\java 
-cp 
    C:\Users\dcherkassky\.m2\repository\org\datanucleus\datanucleus-maven-plugin\5.0.2\datanucleus-maven-plugin-5.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\dcherkassky\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;
    C:\Users\dcherkassky\.m2\repository\com\advantagegroup\blue-jdo-datanucleus\1.0-SNAPSHOT\blue-jdo-datanucleus-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
    C:\code\bluesky\ui\target\classes;
    ... 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/code/bluesky/ui/jdoEnhancerLog4j.properties 
org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer 
-v 
-api JDO 
-flf C:\Users\DCHERK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\enhancer-680011732335723141.flf"
```

Any ideas why the enhancer can't find `org.json.simple.JSONObject`?

(I tried to provide all the relevant information -- I can add more detail if necessary)

Thanks,
DC

Comment: why is that dependency in the plugin dependencies and not in the project dependencies? This enhancer will look in what is available in the CLASSPATH, by normal class loading so if it can't find it then it ain't there

Comment: It is actually in both!  I was getting desperate and clutching at straws when I wrote the question.  Updating to include a more complete and correct POM file.